# Clips Check appropriate syntax for defrule

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, clips

I am trying to make a program that asks is the claimant homeless, unemployed has no having etc and get a either level 1 or 2 benefit support as the answer but I can't load this in Clips. I get the error below

**code**

```
(defrule Claimant
(Claimant-is homeless)
(Claimant-is unemployed)
(Claimant-is nosavings)
(Claimant-is dependants)
(Claimant-is disabled))

(deftemplate Benefit
   (slot benefit))

(defrule Level1
   Claimant(homesless yes) (unemployed yes) (nosavings no) (dependants yes) (disabled yes))
   =>
   (assert (Benefit (benefit level1)))
   (printout t "You get level 1 benefit support" crlf))

(defrule Level2
   Claimant(homesless yes) (unemployed yes) (nosavings no) (dependants no) (disabled no))
   =>
   (assert (Benefit (benefit level2)))
   (printout t "You get level 2 benefit support" crlf))
```

**error**

```
Defining defrule: Claimant 
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::Claimant
   (Claimant-is homeless)
   (Claimant-is unemployed)
   (Claimant-is nosavings)
   (Claimant-is dependants)
   (Claimant-is disabled)
   )
Defining deftemplate: Benefit
Defining defrule: Level1 
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::Level1
   Claimant
Defining defrule: Level2 
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::Level2
   Claimant
FALSE
CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax has several problems that must be corrected.

The design could also be simplified (but I will not talk about that aspect).

The following shows an equivalent version with corrections.

**homeless.clp**

```
(deftemplate Claimant
  (slot homeless (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values yes no))
  (slot unemployed (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values yes no))
  (slot nosavings (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values yes no))
  (slot dependants (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values yes no))
  (slot disabled (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values yes no))
)

(deftemplate Benefit
   (slot benefit (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values level1 level2))
)

(defrule Level1
   (Claimant (homeless yes) (unemployed yes) (nosavings no)
             (dependants yes) (disabled yes))
   =>
   (assert (Benefit (benefit level1)))
   (printout t "You get level 1 benefit support" crlf)
)

(defrule Level2
   (Claimant (homeless yes) (unemployed yes) (nosavings no)
             (dependants no) (disabled no))
   =>
   (assert (Benefit (benefit level2)))
   (printout t "You get level 2 benefit support" crlf)
)
```

Now you can test with

```
(clear)

(load "homeless.clp")

(assert (Claimant (homeless yes) (unemployed yes) (nosavings no) (dependants no) (disabled no)))

(run)
```

and get

```
You get level 2 benefit support
```